# Do followers trigger traps?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I have a follower and there's a location-based trap trigger on the ground (e.g. tripwires that activate a springing spiked log), do my followers trigger the trap if they pass over the trigger, or does it have to be the hero that walks over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after a lot of persuasion I managed to get my follower to walk over a tripline. He didn't trigger it, so pending further investigation, the answer is **no**, followers do not trigger location-based traps.